subprocess not working on pyinstaller exe when its window based(hidden-console)
I have a function that opens up pdf file using a default browser, i tried (os.start()), (os.startfile()), (webbrowser.open()). The function works fine without --no-console or console based, but i dont want the user to see the shell popping up at the startup. App just crashes if the console is hidden. Im currently stuck, Any suggestions?
subprocess.Popen(["start", "", "employeelist.pdf"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


did you check what exception Popen throws at you then ?

Note that start <pdf file> does not open a PDF in the default browser, it will open to whatever program the user has set as default for that file extension. In any case, use QDesktopServices.openUrl().

When you make a build with console=True, does this prints anything on console? I don't know for sure, but I think the shell=True in command means that it is trying to access the shell and execute the command using it, which is not actually present with exe, resulting into error. Can you check the error generated in log file in .kivy/logs/ ?

Post a [mre]. In my Windows machine, it works fine. I used the command pyinstaller -F -w test.py.
